# Get Available Virtual Machine (Classic) Sizes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-.net

We work with ARM and Classic Azure VM's.

For ARM VM we use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute?view=azure-dotnet) namespace ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute/)). For Classic VM we use [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.aspx) namespace ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute/)).

I need to find available sizes for specified VM.

I can do it using [ListAvailableSizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.virtualmachinesoperationsextensions.listavailablesizes?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Compute_VirtualMachinesOperationsExtensions_ListAvailableSizes_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Compute_IVirtualMachinesOperations_System_String_System_String_) method for **ARM VM**. But I can not find relevant method for **Classic VM**...

How I can retrieve available sizes for **Classic VM**?

Comment: Azure Classic VMs are tied to Cloud Services. So see if HostedServiceGetResponse (in particular ComputeCapabilities) returned by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.hostedserviceoperationsextensions.get.aspx helps